# Chef "missing required authentication"

Tags: chef-infra

When I came back from the weekend I was greeted by the following error when attempting to deploy a new node using chef.

I have tried to restart the server and Googled quite a bit but found no solid solution and still have no idea why this would suddenly happen.

We made no changes to the server or the Chef configuration.

Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
merb : chef-server (api) : worker (port 4000) ~ Started request handling: Mon Jul 02 09:57:24 +0200 2012
merb : chef-server (api) : worker (port 4000) ~ Params: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"search"}
merb : chef-server (api) : worker (port 4000) ~ Mixlib::Authentication::MissingAuthenticationHeader: missing required authentication header(s) 'X_OPS_SIGN', 'X_OPS_USERID', 'X_OPS_TIMESTAMP', 'X_OPS_CONTENT_HASH' - (Merb::ControllerExceptions::BadRequest)
/usr/share/chef-server-api/app/controllers/application.rb:48:in `authenticate_every'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort this out simply by restarting the server that chef was installed on. Restarting the service independently did not solve the problem.